# Unit test for Java regex to match Wed, Sep 15 (XXX, XXX ##) not passing

Tags: java, regex, junit, junit4

I'm trying to match a regex that matches something such as "XXX, XXX ##"

So I tried with this one: `"\\w{3},\\s\\w{3}\\s\\d{2}"` but it isn't working

Including full code this is the method I'm trying to test:

```
public String formatDate(String instruction) {
    Date date = new Date();

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat();

    if (instruction.equalsIgnoreCase("short")) {
        format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM yy");
    }
    else if (instruction.equalsIgnoreCase("full")) {
        format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM yyyy");
    }

    String dateToString = format.format(date);
    //Log.e("exe", dateToString);

    return dateToString;
}
```

this is the unit test:

```
public class SchedulerDateTest {
    SchedulerDate schedulerDate;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        schedulerDate = new SchedulerDate();
    }

    //....

    @Test
    public void testFormatDate() throws Exception {
        assertTrue("if parameter is short I want to receive the date in a short format for example: Wed, Sep 15",
            schedulerDate.formatDate("short")
                    .matches("\\w{3},\\s\\w{3}\\s\\d{2}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please show us your code?  The regex _looks_ right but this doesn't mean you will get the result you want.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, thanks tim I just followed your advice and included more info I was trying a unit test

Comment: I just tested the regex in IntelliJ and it works fine.  Are you sure you are using the input string you think you are?

Comment: From the information you have provided, we are not able to reproduce the issue. Pleas provide [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When writing a question, please make it *Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable*. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

This is all of the above:

```
Date date = new Date();
System.out.println("date = " + date);
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM yy");
String dateToString = format.format(date);
System.out.println("dateToString = '" + dateToString + "'");
System.out.println("matches = " + dateToString.matches("\\w{3},\\s\\w{3}\\s\\d{2}"));
```

*Output*

```
date = Wed Sep 09 22:16:21 EDT 2015
dateToString = 'Wed, Sep 15'
matches = true
```

By printing the intermediate values, you'll be able to see where things might go wrong.

It is likely a language issue on your end, e.g. if I switch `Locale`:

```
Locale.setDefault(Locale.CANADA_FRENCH);
```

*Output*

```
date = Wed Sep 09 22:19:17 EDT 2015
dateToString = 'mer., sept. 15'
matches = false
```

Comment: thanks very much that was the problem do you know why changing Locale affected the result?

Comment: Because it's designed that way. First sentence of the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html): "`SimpleDateFormat` is a concrete class for formatting and parsing dates **in a locale-sensitive manner**".